# HTTP Sockets in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

```
request = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)requestMethod, (CFURLRef) sURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
```

what is parameters and variable this code , can give good reference eBook ,pdf.......

Comment: this has nothing to do with xcode4, please remove that tag. You can add a tag like cocoa but this is not an xcode issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at NSURLRequest. It is much more straightforward for a beginner and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to start from the [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html)